# Jersey bean validation - return validation message for bad requests

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

Is it possible to return a validation annotations message in the response for bad responses? I thought this was possible but I have noticed that our projects are not given detailed bad request messages.

```
@NotNull(message="idField is required")
@Size(min = 1, max = 15) 
private String idField;
```

I'd like to see "idField is required" returned if a request is made that's missing the idField. I am using jersey 2.0. What I'm seeing for a response is this...

```
{
  "timestamp": 1490216419752,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Bad Request",
  "path": "/api/test"
}
```

Comment: You should show how you have configured the validator.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like your Bean validation exception(ConstraintViolationException) is translated by one of your ExceptionMappers. You can register an `ExceptionMapper` for `ConstraintViolationException` as shown below and return data in the format you want. `ConstraintViolationException` has all the information you are looking for.

```
@Singleton
@Provider
public class ConstraintViolationMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

  @Override
  public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException e) {
    // There can be multiple constraint Violations
    Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = e.getConstraintViolations();
    List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : violations) {
        messages.add(violation.getMessage()); // this is the message you are actually looking for

    }
    return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(messages).build();
  }

}
```

Comment: Within the custom constraint validator is there a way to add multiple messages for each constraint that is violated?

Comment: @Half_Duplex you can get a list of violations from the exception via ex.getConstraintViolations()  , and they all have their own messages , you can construct your response message as you wish. I simply use the List at mxb's answer

Answer (score 1):

Building upon Justin response, here it is a version that uses Java 8 stream API:

```
@Singleton
@Provider
public class ConstraintViolationMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException e) {
        List<String> messages = e.getConstraintViolations().stream()
            .map(ConstraintViolation::getMessage)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(messages).build();
    }

}
```